# Using "this" accesses outer scope variable

Tags: kotlin, matrix, scope, jvm, this

I wrote a quick little matrix operations library and I wanted to shorten my code for this function:

```kotlin
private fun transpose(): Matrix {
  val result = Matrix(cols, rows)
  loopThrough { row, col ->
    result.data[col][row] = data[row][col]
  }
  return result
}
```

my matrix class is something like this:

```kotlin
class Matrix(val rows: Int, val cols: Int) {
  var data = Array(rows) {FloatArray(cols) {0f} }
  //some other stuff
  fun loopThrough(action: (i: Int, j: Int) -> Unit): Matrix {
    data.forEachIndexed { row, it -> it.forEachIndexed { col, _ ->
      action(row, col)
    }}
    return this
  }
}
```

what I tried to do was:

```kotlin
class Matrix(val rows: Int, val cols: Int) {
  //somewhere in matrix class
  val data = //2d array like above: lets call this upper-data
  fun transpose() = Matrix(cols,rows).loopThrough { row,col ->
    data[row][col] = this@Matrix.data[col][row] // i want data[row][col] to refer to the new Matrix's data
    // this@Matrix.data is upper-data
  }
}
```

Sorry if this is confusing, but I want to set the new matrix's data to the changed `upper-data`. However, from what I understand, both `data` and `this@Matrix.data` refer to `upper-data`.
How can I call the new matrix's data in its loopThrough function? (Congrats if you are not confused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the design of `loopThrough` questionable in the first place. You're effectively looping through the elements of the matrix in the implementation, but you're ignoring them from the API standpoint (just providing i/j coordinates). Also, why return the matrix itself?

Technically, all `loopThrough` does at the moment is help the caller write a loop that they could have written themselves with the public `rows` and `cols` properties.

If you add a parameter with the actual cell value to your `action` lambda, it will make this API more useful IMO (and you could call it `forEachIndexed` to follow conventions):

```kotlin
class Matrix(val rows: Int, val cols: Int) {
  val data = Array(rows) { FloatArray(cols) { 0f } }

  fun forEachIndexed(action: (i: Int, j: Int, value: Float) -> Unit) {
    data.forEachIndexed { i, row ->
        row.forEachIndexed { j, value ->
            action(i, j, value)
        }
    }
  }

  fun transposed(): Matrix = Matrix(cols, rows).also { newMatrix ->
      forEachIndexed { i, j, value -> newMatrix.data[j][i] = value }
  }
}
```

Also, the name `transposed` would better match the stdlib conventions because it creates a new matrix, while `transpose` could be understood as mutating the current matrix (see `sort`/`sorted` for lists).

Also, `data` doesn't need to be `var` here.

Comment: Well I saw how other matrix libraries do this and I ended up writing it like you said. I left this question posted just out of curiosity  to see if there is another way.